# How can I fill e-mail on website via console

Tags: javascript

How can I fill e-mail via Console in Google Chrome ?

[image: photo]

I have inspected the element and results are below:

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="username" placeholder="Podaj swój e-mail albo numer telefonu" autocomplete="username" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" required="required" maxlength="524288" minlength="4" class="form-input custom-focus">
```

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById('email').value = 'sample@email.com';
```

but it do not change email on website.

Comment: You won't see the change when you inspect the element, the dynamic value is not in the DOM attributes. But the new value should still be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITed**

*Yesterday* i use the incorrect selector :(

```
<script>
document.getElementById('email').value = '';
document.getElementById('email').placeholder = 'sample@email.com';
</script>
```

*Today*
i checked your [site](https://login.tidal.com/authorize) and i tried to change Selector to the querySelector and it change the placeholder pretty fine.

```
document.querySelector('[type=username]').placeholder = 'sample@email.com'
```

***the "Continue" button is not active*** ,
we should ask ourselves why he is not active?
Simply because has the disabled attribute, So
*to active* the button "Continue" we should use either :

- by setting  **disabled** *property* of submit to false:

```
document.querySelector('[type=submit]').disabled = false;
```

- or just remove the attribute by the method **removeAttribute**

```
document.querySelector('[type=submit]').removeAttribute('disable')
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but unfortunately it does not work, I have tried it for the page  https://listen.tidal.com/login and the field is still not changed.

Comment: No problem, you help me when you give me the site web and i update the post check it out, and i hope it works to you.

Comment: Thank you for new hint. I have modified it a little bit by changing on .value instead .placeholder. And now it really place white font email.
    
document.querySelector('[type=username]').value = 'sample@email.com';
  
But I struggle with other thing, the "Continue" button is not active. I cannot click on it.

Comment: i try it just right now, and it works when you type four letters?

Comment: When I refresh a website and place in Console:     
document.querySelector('[type=username]').value = 'sample@email.com';     
hit enter, the button is not active.

Comment: gotcha, i update the post again check it out,i fix *the button is not active*,So to active or enable the button you should remove the *disabled* property by using either property disabled put it to false or by removing it using removeAttribute('disabled')

Comment: Indeed    document.querySelector('[type=submit]').disabled = false;   works (change button color on white) even if you don't provide the email, what I think is nok. If you provide the email and use the command document.querySelector('[type=submit]').disabled = false;  the button did not do its job. Maybe first click simulation on the field would help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226176/discussion-between-tom-and-steveeverst).